# Pass context to Async class

Tags: java, android

I'm calling an `Async` class from my main activity class. When the `POST` has been executed I want to return the result back to the main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, AsyncResponse{
    public Context context;
    PostKey asyncTask = new PostKey(context);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        asyncTask.delegate = this;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        asyncTask.delegate = this;
        new PostKey(context).execute(keyValue);
    }

    public void processFinish(String output){
        //this you will received result fired from async class of    onPostExecute(result) method.
        Log.d("Result", output);
    }
}


public class PostKey extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
    public Context context;

    public PostKey(Context context){
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return postData(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        delegate = (AsyncResponse) context;
    }

    delegate.processFinish(result);
}

public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

Whenever I try to run the app I immediately get a fatal error caused by a nullpointer exception. The nullpointer refers to the following:

```
public PostKey(Context context){
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

& 
`PostKey asyncTask = new PostKey(context);`

In the second case I can get that `context` is empty, but I have to pass the variable here.

Comment: In your main activity, `public Context context;` is declared but never given a value? It is null.. so trying to call the PostKey constructor, which attempts to invoke the `getApplicationContext()` function on a null object will definitely give you a NullPointerException.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Gosu In every code snippet I found the `context` variable was set in the async class. Because of `private PostKey(Context context){}` I have to pass the variables in the main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Oryna you passing null context value as in parameter just replace these lines with this

```
 new PostKey(context).execute(keyValue);
```

to

```
 new PostKey(MainActivity.this).execute(keyValue);
```

and the constructor for the async task replace the code

```
    public PostKey(Context context){
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

with

```
public PostKey(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Activity` is already a `Context`, so you don't to keep a reference to it. Just use `this`. On the other hand the Activity has to go through its lifecycle before you can use the context. Remove

```
public Context context;
PostKey asyncTask = new PostKey(context);
```

and add

```
PostKey asyncTask = new PostKey(this);
```

in your `onCreate`. And please, add `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` as first thing in your `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

try to use `this.context = getApplicationContext();` instead